# An $R$-algebra $A$ is simple if and only if $A$ is a simple right $A^{\text{opp}}\otimes A$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

A simple $R$-algebra $A$ is a unital right $R$-module on which is defined a bilinear mapping that is associative and where $A$ has no non-zero proper submodules ($A$ is simple). We define an opposite algebra $A^{\text{opp}}$ to be just the same as $A$ but with reversed multiplication $\square$; i.e. $a\square b=ba,\;a,b\in A^{\text{opp}}$. And $A^e$ is defined as $A^{\text{opp}}\otimes A$. My question is about the following proof from the book Associative Algebras from R.S. Pierce:
[image]
I do not understand how they got to the conclusion of (i) so fast and I would like to know whether someone could help me out in understanding this very small proof or providing proper reading material that clarifies what is related to this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the page on the book ?

Comment: @KonKan the page is 219

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An $A^e$ submodule is the same thing as a submodule of the regular bimodule ${}_{A}A_A$, which in turn is the same thing as a two-sided ideal of the algebra $A$ .

So, part (i) of the lemma could be stated as:

> $A$ is a simple algebra $\Leftrightarrow$ $A$ is a simple right $A^e$-module $\Leftrightarrow$ the ${}_{A}A_A$-bimodule is simple.

Since you are asking for some further reading, maybe it would be helpful to take a look at the book of [Drozd-Kirichenko](https://www.imath.kiev.ua/~drozd/drozd-kirichenko_en.pdf): See par. 4.1, p. 69-70, up to  proposition 4.1.1 and the comments of p. 73 (right before theorem 4.2.4).

(In general an $A$-$B$-bimodule ${}_A M_B$ is the same thing with a right $B\otimes A^{op}$ module:  Given an $A$-$B$-bimodule $M$ we can always view this as a right $B\otimes A^{op}$-module setting $m(b\otimes a^{op})=amb$. Conversely, if $M$ is a right  $B\otimes A^{op}$-module then we get an $A$-$B$-bimodule by setting $am=m(1\otimes a^{op})$ and $mb=m(b\otimes 1)$.
 In the same manner ${}_A M_B$ may be viewed as a right $A^{op}\otimes B$ module via $m(a^{op}\otimes b)=amb$ (see the comment in user's @Lord Shark the Unknown [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3347595/195021)).

Comment: Ah. thanks. This book you referred to looks a bit friendlier than "Associative Algebras".

Answer (score 1):

The two-sided ideals of $A$ are precisely the right $A^e$-submodules of $A$.

A simple algebra is one without non-trivial two-sided ideals.

A simple module is one without non-trivial submodules.

Comment: I do not see how right $A^e$-submodules of $A$ work somehow as two sided ideals for $A$. The algebras are not necessarily commutative.

Comment: $A^e$ acts (on the right) on $A$ via $x\cdot(a\otimes  b)=axb$. Immediately from this a two-sided ideal of $A$ must be an $A^e$-submodule. For the converse consider elements $a\otimes1$ and $1\otimes a$ of $A^e$.